# Regex: extract strings from pattern string1.string2'string3 where string1 can contain a '.' character

Tags: c++, regex

I need a regex to extract string1, string2, and string3 from a string of the form:
`string1.string2'string3`. The separators '.' and ''' may not be present in the input.

The problem is that string1 may contain a period character '.' too so the rightmost period has to be used for extracting the string1.

What may help is that there is a condition on the length of the string2 that may be imposed: it must consist of exactly 3 alphabetic characters, it a country code such as USA, JPN.

Example:

```
input: Hello -> string1=Hello 
input: Hello.b ->  string1=Hello.b 
input: Hello.USA -> string1=Hello, string2=USA 
input: Hello.c.JPN -> string1=Hello.c, string2=JPN
input: Hello.d.r.USA'Today -> string1=Hello.d.r, string2=USA, string3=Today
input: Hello.d'Today -> string1=Hello.d, string3=Today
```

Input strings may be either `std::string` or `std::wstring`

Comment: Where's the code? What *exactly* are you having trouble with?

Comment: @MrEricSir this wouldn't be tough to do in code but for various reasons I need to use C++ regex

Comment: Anonymous downvoter: this is regex question and all such questions are recommended to specify the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::regex re("([^\\.']+(\\.(?![^']{3}('|$))[^\\.']+)*)(\\.([^']{3}))?('(.+))?");
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PHRJJI88708)

Obligatory:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. --  Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. As for the obligatory: apparently the context is also obligatory these days to please unhappy down voters : I am working with the module that already uses regex heavily. My boss wants regex solution.

Comment: Igor, I wouldn't ask this question if I were familiar with C++ regex. Could you please add the code that actually extracts the strings as described in the question before I accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I trust you know how to follow links. There's one in my answer.

Comment: BTW Igor, after spending some time trying to understand how this works, I think that matching a dot character with negative pattern look ahead is really nice idea. I've learned some regex today 